# Shell script CP cannot overwrite directory

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, cp, sparkle

our users have written a shell script to copy an application into into the /Applications folder on OSX. it works great the first time, but the second time they get an error. This is a new development, it apparently used to work fine before we changed the App name.

The shell script runs the following:

```
cp -a ApplicationName.app /Applications
open -a '/Applications/ApplicationName.app/Contents/MacOS/ApplicationName' --args -LSRC autolaunch
```

The first time it runs, it works fine, the application is copied over and then it launches. the second time it comes back with the following errors

```
[jrivera@chamomile] $ sudo ./InstallScript.sh /SRNM ABC1234567
cp: cannot overwrite directory /Applications/ApplicationName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Headers with non-directory ApplicationName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Headers
cp: cannot overwrite directory /Applications/ApplicationName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Resources with non-directory ApplicationName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Resources
cp: cannot overwrite directory /Applications/ApplicationName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fr_CA.lproj with non-directory ApplicationName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fr_CA.lproj
cp: cannot overwrite directory /Applications/ApplicationName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/pt.lproj with non-directory ApplicationName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Resources/pt.lproj
cp: cannot overwrite directory /Applications/ApplicationName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/Current with non-directory ApplicationName.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/Current
```

I'm not exactly sure why that's happening. it's the exact same script in the exact same location copying the exact same things 30 seconds apart. I dug into each and the directories and files all appear the exact same file type. I tried adding other commands to the cp to force it (-RfXv) but got the same thing. Any ideas? maybe it's a strange thing with sparkle?

Answer (score 3):

I would suspect that the problematic files/directories have some extended attributes, and that `cp` is having problems overwriting the target when it has those attributes.  (`cp` when preserving permissions often seems unreliable on different platforms).

Given that, there are a couple of workarounds to explore:

- remove the target `/Applications/ApplicationName.app` before re-copying it.
- use `rsync`, e.g.,

  rsync -vaz ApplicationName.app/ /Applications/ApplicationName.app

Removing the target first may interfere with people using it while you are updating it; `rsync` works incrementally (and almost always updates more rapidly than `cp`).

Comment: I think the destination parameter on rsync should be /Applications/ rather than the .app directory itself. Also using `-z` probably only serves to slow rsync down, as it's working locally. Using rsync instead of cp is a great tip though, thanks!